# Android WebView with URL setting

Tags: android, url, webview, settings

I am wanting to set the URL of a webview via some sort of settings menu. The purpose of this is to create a web front end to a piece of equipment and the equipment will have it's IP address set.

I want to be able to set this IP address as the URL of the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store that URL in a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) object and consider using a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) screen for editing it.

Answer (score 0):

WbView has loadUrl method, use it like this:

```
String webUrlStr = "http://www.url.com";
mWebView.loadUrl(webUrlStr);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can call loadUrl passing in a different String any time you want. it is not permanent.